# Click on banner to register to the blog

Tags: login, user-registration

Hi to all I would like to add a "premium" section to my wordpress blog and I would like to force users to click on a banner before being allowed to register to my blog, any step 2 step idea on how to solve this problem?
The banner will be html or js.
Thanks a lot to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a WAY open-ended question. I feel that if you did some research you'd find LOTS of answers. Here's how I would go about it.

Install or modify your code to use a members only plugin. Lock all the Non-Member pages. I'm confused on what you men by check a banner, but if the banner is just going to a registration page then block that page unless a query string something like `example.net/register?banner=true` has been set. If they go to `example.net/register` it would return false.

I'm not sure I answer your question like I said it's super open-ended. That's how I would do it. (if I understand the question)

**EDIT:**

You'll need to use a PHP [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) or even a [$_COOKIE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to see if the user clicked the banner. I would do something like this.

Make a category "premium" and assign all preminum page to that category.

Add this to your functions.php in your theme

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'premium_redirect' );

function premium_redirect(){
   //see if post is in category of premium
   if(in_category('premium')){
        //see if the banner variable is set
        $banner_check =$_GET['banner'];
        //set the session (or cookie)
        if($banner_check == 'true'){$_SESSION['banner'] = 'true';}
        ///see if the $banner and the $_SESSION is set if not take them to the banner page
        if($_SESSION['banner'] != 'true'){
                 wp_redirect('http://example.net/bannerpage');
        }
     return;
    } //end cat check
return;
}
```

then have your banner link to `example.net/premiumpage?banner=true`

I haven't tested this but I us similar approaches all the time. You may also need to use a custom post type for pages instead of `in_category` see http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type

Comment: what I wanna do is something like...Click on AdSense to login (not really AdSense because I know they will ban me but some ads that allow also incentivized traffic)

Comment: Then my solution would work. You could also use `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` and only show the login if whatever method you choose is true.

Comment: Also, I'm not going to give you a lecture on ethics but I think this is not an ethical way to have people access your site. Unless of course you state that VERY CLEAR in your terms.

Comment: This will be a new way to pay for premium contents :-) User only has to click (not to pay) Advertisers know that the clicks are incentivized (they like it) I earn a little money.
No victims everyone wins :-)
Could you please be a little more specific? I can't understand how to implement what you are telling to me (PHP almost Noob here) :P

Comment: I just posted some example code. It's not prefect but gets you started.